# Downloading MODIS tiles with rts package in R?

Tags: r, modis

I'm having trouble using `ModisDownload()`. Every time I use the command, I get the following error message:

```
Error in .getModisList(x = xx, h = h, v = v, dates = dates, opt = opt,  : 
  Download error: Server does not response!
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In merge.list(list(...), .opts) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In merge.list(list(...), .opts) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In merge.list(list(...), .opts) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
4: In merge.list(list(...), .opts) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
5: In merge.list(list(...), .opts) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

I'm using the code below to download MODIS titles.

```
setwd('C:/modis')
library(raster)
library(MODIS)
library(rts)
library(RCurl)

x = 'MOD14A1'

ModisDownload(x = x,h = c(17,18),v = c(4,5),
  dates = '2011.05.01', mosaic = F, proj = F)
```

The example for this code is also coming from this website: http://r-gis.net/?q=ModisDownload.

Comment: I just installed the MODIS package and there's *no* `ModisDownload` function. There might be one in the `rts` package. Please make your code complete.

Comment: What is inside `x`? Is a Modis Product Name or is something else?

Comment: By the way... this fuction is from `rts` package

Comment: Even after installing the rts package, I'm still getting the same error message. X = "MOD14A1"

Comment: are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Not sure. How do I find out if I'm behind a firewall?

Comment: ask your IT people.

Comment: now I am getting this error message                                                             Error in .._MD_curlHandle <<- RCurl::getCurlHandle() : 
  cannot change value of locked binding for '.._MD_curlHandle'

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be your NASA authentication. The `ModisDownload` function is part of the `rts` package, whose last version (not on CRAN yet, as far as I know) is updated to allow for the necessary login in the NASA server before searching/downloading MODIS image. Try

```
devtools::install_github('babaknaimi/rts')  # must install the latest one
library(rts)

setNASAauth("yourNASAlogin", "yourNASApassword", update = T) # authenticates at NASA's server
> username and password are successfully updated...!
```

Trying your code above after login in  successfully found and downloaded the MODIS files you were interested in the raw `.hdr` format. If you are interested in having them as a geotiff, you should install the Modis Download Tool (MRT) and use `ModisDowload()` to download, mosaic and reproject together the tiles you want.